# iOS trouble with size class - incorrect size view

Tags: ios, layout, view, size-classes

I'm meeting (again :D) a problem with size classes.

I've a view in a UIViewController which has several constraints setted in the Any x Any size class.

I set a width constraint at 200px, and a height constraint at 200px.

For the Regular x Regular, I wanted a bigger view, so I unchecked these constraints, to set news constraints, with width at 300px and height at 300px.

The problem is, when I want to get in my code the size of these view, I haven't the correct size for iPad. (Regular x Regular size class)

I tried to get it methods :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews 
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

With the log :

```
NSLog(@"size %f - %f", self.viewTest.frame.size.height, self.viewTest.frame.size.width);
```

And it's only in the function viewDidAppear where I've the correct size (so 300px * 300px.)

The problem is, if the user "rotate" the iPad, this method isn't called again.....

So I don't understand, why I don't succeed to retrieve the correct size in the others methods ? (In all of my code, I'm doing nothing special with this view, currently, I just want to get the size of this view.)

Answer (score 0):

You could just override the `viewWillTransitionToSize` method in your controller and do whatever you want to do when changing orientation.

Swift:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    //code
}
```

Obj-C:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    //code
}
```